# How to keep an open file handle in a shell script on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

A trick some daemons use, is to open a newly created temp file-handle, remove it from the file system, then execute the file descriptor.

This can be done from C, but I was curious if this would be possible from a shell script?

---

Example use-case for running a temporary binary:

- Compile the binary to a temp location.
- Open its file-handle
- Remove it from the file-system
- `exec` the file descriptor.

This way `exec` takes over the process and we don't need to worry about cleaning up the temporary file.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: No, since I didn't see how to call `fopen` or `open` from a shell script, although I expect there is probably a way to do it - all search hits I got lead to C code examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is roughly equivalent, and pretty simple:

```
cp /path/to/the/executable /tmp/blah
/tmp/blah arg1 arg2 &
rm -f /tmp/blah
wait
```

The `wait` at the end will block until the background (`&`) job finishes.

Be sure to add error checking or `set -e` before running this code, as you might otherwise execute or remove something you didn't intend.  And probably you'll want to generate a unique temporary filename instead of `blah`.

Comment: While this works quite well, unlike `exec` this doesn't forward the exit code, and has the slight disadvantage that the shell process keeps running in the background.

Comment: @ideasman42: This actually does forward the exit code, by virtue of the fact that `wait` returns the exit code of the command waited upon, and the fact that Bash returns the exit code of the final command of a script.  If you want you could make it more explicitly by adding return status capture at the end, but this has no practical consequence.

Comment: For some reason in my tests with bash; `wait` isn't returning the exit code unless I do `wait; exit $?`

Comment: do you mean that `wait ; echo $? ` always returns `0` ? Good luck.

Comment: No, I mean the `exit`, as in the shell script doesn't forward the exit-code to the exit status of the shell script its self.